# Spring Tool Suite IDE not highlighting JSP files

Tags: jsp, spring-tool-suite

I have to create a Spring Boot WEB app but the JSP pages are show as plain text without any highlight or marker.

How to configure STS to show JSP files as Eclipse do?

Using STS 4.0.0.M12.

Comment: I don't think we need to configure anything extra , by default whatever eclipse do same STS will do .

Comment: Then something is very wrong here....

Comment: @AvijitBarua the problem is not the code itself. In Eclipse I can receive some assistence from the IDE when it highlights the code and show some tips and hints like "This tag is wrong" or "I can't find the JSP file you're including here"... In STS it is just a plain text file. STS don't know it is a JSP file. Nothing wrong when compile and run.

Comment: open that jsp file with html editor.

Comment: Bingo! There is a "JSP Editor" .. after open the first solved for all of them.

Comment: And what if I don't have a JSP Editor? It's just not in the list.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

STS to show JSP files as Eclipse does you have to install the plugin form eclipse marketplace.

On your, STS go to

**help>**  *eclipse marketplace*

and search for

> Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools

click install when it's completely installed simply restart the IDE, now you can create jsp file

Answer (score 9):

You will have to install the plugin "*Java Enterprise Java & Web Developer Tools*" form Eclipse Marketplace in your Spring Tool Suite to show JSP files in the Eclipse editor.

On your, Spring Tool Suite go to

1. Click Help Menu in Eclipse
2. Select Eclipse Marketplace

Now search 'Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools'

[Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools Plugin Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1sGj.png)

Install & choose to restart the IDE when prompted by IDE.

Answer (score 4):

help> eclipse marketplace

Install Eclipse Enterprise Java And Web Developer Tools 3.21

[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5IAj.png)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problam..after install  **Eclipse Enterprise Java And Web Developer Tools 3.21**  and all are work good.

help> eclipse marketplace

Answer (score 1):

Just go the Help -> **Eclipse Marketplace** --> search for - **Eclipse Web Developer tools(lates version)** --> install now --> confirm validation --> you are done...ready to go

Answer (score 0):

For the Spring tool suite 4.

By default, the JSP files are not included in the suite.

In your suite, Just go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> type Eclipse Enterprise Java and Web Developer Tools (version = latest one is 3.22) and install it

Then restart your suite and check now.

Answer (score 0):

Go to help -> Eclipse Marketplace -> Search for JSP -> You will see Eclipse Enterprise Java and Web Developer Tools 3.21. Install the plugin.
After installation completed restart the IDE.

Comment: Try this way you can resolve the issue